# Who is this X-Wing pilot?

Tags: star-wars

While reading up on some deleted scenes from Return of the Jedi, I came across this picture of an x-wing pilot played by actress Vivienne Chandler. What I'd like to know is, who is she, what squadron did she fly with and, even though she's in a deleted scene, is she still part of the canon of Star Wars.

[image: female x-wing pilot]

Comment: Fun fact, that's the helmet prop (with added blast shield) that Luke wears on the Falcon when he's learning to use the Force.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wookieepedia's Chandler page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vivienne_Chandler):

> Though her scene was cut, Chandler portrayed Dorovio Bold during the Battle of Endor. Her scene was not included in the Blu-Ray release of the film (sourced in [this blog](https://starwarsaficionado.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/girl-power-jedis-female-fighter-pilots.html))

Whether she's G-canon or not is hard to tell (not being on the Blu-Ray would indicate she's not), but she's C-canon, the character's [Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dorovio_Bold) says:

> Her photo was revealed years later on StarWars.com's Hyperspace, and she was later named in The Complete Visual Dictionary.

This makes her C-canon at least. ([She was previously in starwars.com Databank](https://web.archive.org/web/20091213144113/https://www.starwars.com/databank/character/doroviobold/index.html), but no longer appears.)

Comment: You might want to update this now that her name was included in the [Visual Encyclopedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Encyclopedia) (which makes her officially canon).